# TIN gets distorted using hard clip to edit it?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, clip, tin, masking

I have two cross sections from which I have created a TIN as can be seen in the following image. For removing the extra outer portion of the TIN, I created a polygon from the cross-sections and edited the TIN by hard-clipping the polygon, but the resulting TIN is always distorted and some areas are surprisingly missing.

[image]

Comment: Is the clipping polygon completely within the TIN extent?

Comment: The clipping polygon is created by connecting the cross-sections both ends together. So two edges are the same as the two cross sections and the other two edges are created by connecting the cross-section end points.

Comment: That's odd. Can you upload the TIN and the clipping polygon and share?

Comment: I just try hard clip on a very complex TIN and although it threw a "failed to execute" error it actually clipped the TIN correctly.  I tried both high field shape (3D) and none and both worked. I am using version 10.2.2 If i remember correctly there were some issues with editing TINs in version 10.0. Do you have the latest updates/patches for version 10?

Comment: I tried it using version 10.1 too but I am having the same issue. The TIN gets distorted and the clipped result is totally different. I am not sure what is going on. Any idea on how to share my data?

Comment: dropbox link or similar would work

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pdgk1wl2ncczj5s/AACfeXEDB_3QmeFygyjqwKada?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using 10.2 but had no issues clipping your TIN. Your polygon is not a 3D feature so you may have incorrectly set the **Height Field** parameter which by default is, in this case, set to iD - this will force to clip the TIN at that height which is 0.

Set the Height Field to NONE and run it again:
[image]

The resulting TIN will be clipped as follows:
[image]